# Is it possible to add values with duplicate keys to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have something like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
  NSString *fname;
  NSString *lname;
}

NSString *keys = @"a","a","b","b","b"....";
for(NSString *key in keys)
{
    Person *newPerson; //alloc new person
    [myMutableDictionary setValue:newPerson forKey:key];
}
```

The above code will override the value with same key since NSDictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys. How can I do this?
I can do the above code by NSMutableArray, as in [array addObject:newPerson]; but it takes longer to fetch for (Key,value) as opposed to NSDictionary? My data is about 400,000 items, Any idea on how to do this efficiently? I need to load it once and do many fetches on it - No coreData, I tried it, its slow.

Comment: Make the value a mutable array of `Person` not just a single person.

Comment: Can you use different keys? Maybe combine the index and the key to create a unique key? (keys = a1, a2, b1, b2...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an `NSMutableArray` as a key you can add multiple `Person` objects for the same key.

```
NSString *keys = @"a","a","b","b","b", ...;
for(NSString *key in keys)
{
    Person *newPerson; //alloc new person
    NSMutableArray *people;
    if(!(people = [myMutableDictionary objectForKey:key]))
    {
        people = [NSMutableArray array];
        [myMutableDictionary setValue:people forKey:key];
    }

    [people addObject:newPerson];
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, even though I changed my approach. I ended up   making the key unique and made the value an Array. For instance, instead of , (a,val1)(a,val2)..I have (a,{val1,val2}).

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my example does?